# Restrict accesses to the uploaded contents in Wordpress (through plugin or httpd config)

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache

We have Wordpress website on our linux system. It host number of private files which are visible to who can login. We set the permission of those files as full-read (rwxr-xr-x). The problem is all the content are accessible to anyone who has the direct link! The main question is how can I restrict accesses to these direct link only to logged-in users?

Is there any Wordpress plugin or httpd configuration doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would place a `.htaccess` file with `deny from all` clause within the root of the uploads folder.

Comment: It works with uploads directory nicely. We have many sub-directories in the uploads which are still open. Does htaccess have a recursive option or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

I tackled the problem temporarily by modifying httpd.conf to add special policy for the uploads sub-directories:

```
        <Directory /var/www/wp-content/uploads>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from XXX.XXX.XX
                Deny from all
        </Directory>
```

This permits only to our local users to access the contents. However, I am still curious how wordpress can permit this access to only logged in users.